# vscode: when dealing with tex file, clicking preview button would do nothing. no error, no warning, no prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode 1.40.0 on mac.

when dealing with markdown file, the preview functionality works well

[image]

[image]

when dealing with tex file, clicking preview button would do nothing. no error, no warning, no prompt

[image]

I've tried every option in the menu shown below.

[image]

only "set default viewer" shows an reaction, shown as below.

[image]

whatever I choose, this prompt shows up.

[image]

my pdf viewer settings (latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer) looks like this

[image]

thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: Install [LaTeX Preview - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajshort.latex-preview)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, I've installed that. does not work either.

Comment: @DavidPostill Did you use [LaTeX Preview - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajshort.latex-preview) recently? which version you are using?